# How to generate a project's settings designer file on build in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mercurial, automation

We use a shared Mercurial repository and do not store any designer files in them since they auto-generated. When we create a new clone, I want the Visual Studio solution to *automatically* generate all the missing designer files.

After much searching I've not found a way for this happen. I did find some things on generating web aspx.designer files, but this doesn't help as this is for a C# application and library projects. I figured it would be a simple pre-build event, but have not found it. The process I'm looking for is upon a new clone, run build, all designer files are created, and then the build process continues.

How can I get the Settings.settings to generate the Settings.Designer.cs file when I clone or when I build?

Comment: By any designer I will specify I mean those which are available in Visual Studio by default and not third-party add-ons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that this file is not generated during build but at design time; in other words, it is produced by Visual Studio, not MSBuild. You can check by yourself deleting the generated file and invoking a full rebuild.

Your only option is to find a way to call the SettingsSingleFileGenerator class, as the does the IDE, then you package such call in an MSBuild task.

Honestly I do not think it worth the effort: add the file to source control and you have done.

Comment: Answer is not useful.  I need to regenerate this file at build time.

Comment: What if the designer file contains sensitive information like connection strings?

Comment: this is a different topic, drifting from OP, and there are many approaches to manage config data, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749346/web-config-sensitive-settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `resgen` on your `.resx` files.

To do what you want you need to write a script that runs resgen on all your resx files and then associate it with a [Post-clone](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc) hook.

You will need to somehow distribute this hook to all developers.

You may find it would be better to run the strip on a Post-update hook rather than just a Post-clone hook. (Unless you can guarantee that no ones going to add anymore resx files).

Comment: This looks very promising, but it's specific to the .resx files. Specifically we're looking to generate the code for the Settings.settings file, i.e. Settings.Designer.cs.

Comment: To create your Settings.Designer.cs there is a COM component invoked through certain
inerface, unfortunately which are not specified: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/457189-what-tool-generates-settings-designer-cs